# cats-effect: How to transform `List[IO[A]]` to `IO[List[A]]`

Tags: io, monads, scala-cats

I have an `List[IO[A]]` and I want to convert it to an `IO[List[A]]`
In scalaz I would use `sequenceU` but I don't find the equivalent in cats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problems

```
import cats.implicits._

val x: List[IO[A]] = ...
val y: IO[List[A]] = x.sequence
```